# SolarWinds Information Service (SWIS) hello world

Tags: java, rest, web-services, ssh, solarwinds-orion

I'm looking to authenticate with the `Solarwinds Orion SDK` for Java towards returning a list of devices.  The [sample](https://github.com/solarwinds/OrionSDK/blob/master/Samples/Java/swis-client/src/main/java/com/solarwinds/orionsdk/discovery/Credential.java) code as:

```
package com.solarwinds.orionsdk.discovery;

public class Credential {
    private int credentialId;
    private int order;

    public Credential(int credentialId, int order) {
        setCredentialId(credentialId);
        setOrder(order);
    }

    public int getCredentialId() {
        return credentialId;
    }

    public void setCredentialId(int credentialId) {
        this.credentialId = credentialId;
    }

    public int getOrder() {
        return order;
    }

    public void setOrder(int order) {
        this.order = order;
    }
}
```

1.)  Do I need a `ssh` key to [authenticate](https://thwack.solarwinds.com/thread/122324), or simply my user password?

2.)  Simply run this against the server which is used for GUI admin?

3.)  What steps need to be taken to allow such `API` or `SDK` access to the server?

However, I'm not at all sure that I'm even looking at the appropiate sample code.

Comment: Sorry but I don't know the Java side of the SDK at all. Are you on Thwack (The SolarWinds user site)? If not, join and then contact @tdanner. He is usually very helpful (and wrote the SDK).

Comment: Yes, tdanner responded:  https://thwack.solarwinds.com/thread/125008  and pointed me to the correct API:  https://secure.n-able.com/webhelp/NC_9-1-0_SO_en/Default.htm#SA_docs/API_Level_Integration/API_Integration_WebServiceLevel.html